# What is special about the remainder of two number c in relation to a and b where c=a mod b;

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone provide me some intuition about the remainder in relation to the dividend and divisor?

so let's say c=a mod b;
then what is intuitive about the remainder(c) in relation to a and b;

and we can say also take this question what does the mod do? and what's so special about it!!

//PS:: I am feeling something but not able to think or to say express...

Comment: Did you mean *remainder* when you typed *reminder*?

Comment: note that $\%$ symbol is mostly computer language, in math we use $a \bmod b$ instead.

Comment: ok, edited on the basis of the above two comments...

Answer (score 0):

Is it that that you want to read?

- $ a = b \times (\mbox{an integer, the value of which we are not necessarily interested in}) + (a \% b)$
- $ 0 \leq (a \% b) \lt b$

Or
$(a \% b) = a - b \times (\mbox{as much as you can, as long as the result is } \geq 0) $

Comment: Well, that's just math I want something more than that in this case.